# how can i use wp-ajax in wp-admin root protected for public users?

Tags: ajax, contacts, locked, wp-admin

i have locked my wp-admin root folder by my host
by in my theme like [this page](http://www.onwebsite.ir/contact/) i use wp ajax
and because my wp-admin is locked this form not work
what should had i to do for this problem?
when user submit the form get this alert of protection

```
http://www.onwebsite.ir is requesting your username and password. The site says: “Admins Area!”
```

is there any way i do my ajax requests in an other path?
or is has way for send information protection with form just for ajax file?

and in the second action how can i change wp-login.php file url?

thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the usual method:

```html
<Files admin-ajax.php>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Satisfy any
</Files>
```

Added to the .htaccess file within wp-admin.